# 'reset' remaining elements in dictionary with a value (without boilerplating it), is it possible?

Tags: python, dictionary

So I have the following code (working) for counting up a version number

```
#bump version
version = {
    'Major:': old_version[0],
    'Minor:': old_version[1],
    'Patch:': old_version[2],
    }

version[levelstr] = str(int(version[levelstr]) + 1)

new_version_str = version['Major:'] + "." + version['Minor:'] + "." + version['Patch:']
```

Only I forgot that if for example the major version is incremented, the minor and patch should be zero'ed (same if the minor version, the patch should be zero'ed). Having thus far avoided boilerplating it with if's, I would rather like to avoid code such as the below (as that is quite noisy and clumsy way - but would ofc. work):

```
if levelstr=='Major:':
    version['Minor:'] = '0';
    version['Patch:'] = '0';
```

So basicly is there some clever way to do something like: *set a value to the elements to the right of this element* ? Alternatively i could maybe convert the strings to an index and then work with a sequence instead.. ?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want a `Version` class, where the setters mutate `Major`, `Minor` or `Patch` version type instance variables, depending on the setter.

Or, you could look at probably the worst answer I've ever posted on this site:

```
def increment_version(old_version, key):

    noop = lambda x: x
    incr = lambda x: x+1
    reset = lambda x: 0

    keys = ("Major", "Minor", "Patch")
    operations = (noop, noop, incr, reset, reset)

    yield from map(str, (operations[2 - keys.index(key) + offset](int(char)) for offset, char in enumerate(old_version)))


old_version = "321"
new_version = ".".join(increment_version(old_version, "Major"))

print(new_version)
```

Comment: Nah, im just parsing a text file and incrementing a version number - only used once